# Error executing ifdown and ifup command

Tags: python, wifi, filesystem

I'm running a *python script* to configure the **wifi** interface, but I'm having a problem with the `ifdown` and `ifup` command. It looks like this command has been replaced by:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 down
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

But I can not use this command since I'm using **wifi** library to interact with these files and programs.
The file `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

iface wlan0-kenta inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid kenta
    wireless-channel auto
    wpa-psk #here has code apparently in hexadecimal representing the password,
            #I have already tried to switch to the character password.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why are you using these bizarre commands? None of these are used in current Raspbian.

Comment: I'm using a python library that when trying to connect to a network, uses this command to disable and enable network interface.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this thread on stack overflow which seems to use the **wifi** library. Maybe it will work for you.

[Stack overflow link to using **wifi** library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470626/python-script-for-raspberrypi-to-connect-wifi-automatically)

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me, now I wrote my own wifi network configuration library that did not need this command.

Comment: @kenta And does it work now? If so, please make an answer to tell that your problem is solved. This will also finish your question.